# Появляется другой цвет на фоне SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Появляется другой цвет на градиенте SVG когда начинаем приближать или отдалять изображение (при наведении курсора на блок). Почему и как и справить? Вот пример кода:

```css
.container {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.container:hover .ico {
   filter: url(#gradient-overlay-1);
         fill-rule: evenodd;
  }
.ico {
  fill: #fff;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="ico">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="58" height="58" viewBox="0 0 58 58">
    <path d="M0.000,57.999 L0.000,52.199 L58.000,52.199 L58.000,57.999 L0.000,57.999 ZM40.020,31.899 L18.009,31.899 L11.600,46.399 L5.075,46.399 L26.100,-0.001 L31.900,-0.001 L52.925,46.399 L46.400,46.399 L40.020,31.899 ZM29.000,6.988 L20.561,26.099 L37.439,26.099 L29.000,6.988 Z"
    class="cls-1" />
    <filter id="gradient-overlay-1" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feImage x="0" y="0" width="58" height="58" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB3aWR0aD0iNTgiIGhlaWdodD0iNTgiPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZ3JhZCIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIHkxPSI0NS43NDMiIHgyPSI1OCIgeTI9IjEyLjI1NyI+CiAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSItMC4yNSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZjODAzYiIvPgogIDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMS4yMDUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlODU4NjciLz4KICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEuMjUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlODU4NjciLz4KPC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD4KPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkKSIvPjwvc3ZnPg=="
      />
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feBlend in2="SourceGraphic" result="gradientFill" />
    </filter>
  </svg>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе надо привязать изменение

```
.ico {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

к тем действиям которые ты хочешь. Чтоб заливка менялась, так как тебе надо.

Comment: А можете сделать ваш код запускаемым, чтобы легче был наблюдать эффект?

Answer (score 0):

```
svg {
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

Comment: А можете сделать ваш код запускаемым, чтобы легче был наблюдать эффект?